# Zend_Form set and validate field value manually

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend_Form with a dropdown field.
When the user sets a value in the url this one should be selected as default value in this dropdown.

So what i do at the moment is this:

```
$parlang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang');
if($parlang){
    $this->view->filterForm->getElement('ddLanguage')->setValue($parlang);
}

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if($this->view->filterForm->isValid($_POST)){
...
...
...
```

No i want to check if the value of the variable is even a valid value for the dropdown? How can i check this in coorporation with the form validation. Yes i can check the variable against a array or so but this seems to be "fighting against the framework".

So what is the Zend way to do such a thing?

Edit:
My final solution for all who are interested, is:

```
$parlang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang');
if($parlang){
    $ddLanguage = $this->view->filterForm->ddLanguage;
    if($ddLanguage->isValid($parlang)){
        $ddLanguage->setValue($parlang);
        $language = $parlang;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the other values of your MultiSelect field? Are they a list of country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick test and it looks like one method you can use is `Zend_Form_Element_Select::getMultiOption()` to check if the language exists in the select values.

```
<?php

$parlang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang');

if ($parlang) {
    $el = $this->view->filterForm->getElement('ddLanguage');

    // attempt to get the option
    // Returns null if no such option exists, otherwise returns a
    // string with the display value for the option
    if ($el->getMultiOption($parlang) !== null) {
        $el->setValue($parlang);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your post lead me in the right direction but i made it a litte different. I'm using the isValid method of the form element instead of checking if the value is in the list.

Comment: That works too, I thought of that possibility as well, but if it comes back invalid, you may have to clear the form or element of errors; but I'm not sure though, I didn't try that way.

Answer (score 1):

If your Multiselect element contains a list of country, I would just populate a default in your element value according to the one in the URL.

In order to do so, you could create a custom Zend_Form_Element as follow:

```
class My_Form_Element_SelectCountry extends Zend_Form_Element_Select
{
    protected $_translatorDisabled = true;

    public function init()
    {
        $locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale');

        if (!$locale) {
            throw new Exception('No locale set in registry');
        }

        $countries = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('territory', $locale, 2);
        unset($countries['ZZ']);

        // fetch lang parameter and set US if there is no param
        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $lang = $request->getParam('lang', 'US');

        // sort your country list
        $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, '0');
        setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'en_US');
        asort($countries, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
        setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $oldLocale);

        // check weither the lang parameter is valid or not and add it to the list
        if (isset($countries[$lang])) {
            $paramLang = array($lang => $countries[$lang]);
            $countries = array_merge($paramLang, $countries);
        }        

    $this->setMultiOptions($countries);
}
```

}

You get the idea from this custom form.
If what you're trying to do isn't a Multiselect field filled by a country list but a list of language instead, then the logic is the same, you just need to change the call to the static method `Zend_Locale::getTranslationList()`and grab whatever information you need.

One more thing, if you just want a single element in your Multiselect element, then go for a `Zend_Form_Element_Hidden`.

It's a lot of "if" but I can't understand how looks like your Multiselect element exactly from your question.

Now let's take a look on the validation side, when you're using a Multiselect element, Zend_Framework automatically adds an `InArray` validator, which means that you don't have anything to do to check weither the data sent are correct or not. `isValid` is going to do it for you.

Weither a user let the default parameter and everything will be fine, or he modifies/deletes this parameter and the default parameter (en_US in this case, see code above) is going to be set as a default value for the Multiselect field.

To answer your last question, no it's not against the framework to check a variable set by a user and compare it with an array (from `getTranslationList()`for example). I would say it's even the recommended way to do things.

Comment: It seems wrong to me to extend a form element for just that task. Since this new element can be only used for that task and i want to write my modules as generic as possible. But thanks for your idea.